# Как округлить значения до 2-го знака в Python?

Tags: python, числа, txt, округление

У меня есть txt-файл а в нем столбец с такими значениями:

```
398.4031054903279
777.08739731628975
508.98408257848951
625.770562174858
570.98078802168141
379.3568871484805
322.9235716995849
```

Мне нужно округлить их до сотых долей (или целого) и сохранить в txt. как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно считывать числа из файла, преборазовывать во `float`, а потом использовать у строки метод [format](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/formatirovanie-strok-metod-format.html):

```
with open('input.txt', 'r') as inp, open('output.txt', 'w') as outp:
    for line in inp:
        num = float(line.strip())
        outp.write('{0:.2f}\n'.format(num))
```

Answer (score 6):

Как вариант:

```py
with open("myfile.txt", "r") as f:
    t = f.read()

# Разбиваем по строкам
t = t.split("\n")

with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    for i in t:
        # преобразовываем в число и округляем
        ret = round(float(i), 2)
        # ret = int(ret) # Если нужно до целых 
        f.write(str(ret)+"\n")
```